# SearchView nullPointerException

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте, помогите решить проблему, SearchView выдает nullPointerException.
    <i>

```
// Within which the entire activity is enclosed
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

// ListView represents Navigation Drawer
ListView mDrawerList;

// ActionBarDrawerToggle indicates the presence of Navigation Drawer in the action bar
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// Title of the action bar
String mTitle="";

SearchView mSearchView;

SearchManager searchManager;

ListView mListView;

private final String[] mStrings = {"Hello", "Andrey"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            mStrings));
    mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    mTitle = (String) getTitle();

    // Getting reference to the DrawerLayout
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout1);

    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Getting reference to the ActionBarDrawerToggle
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle( this,
            mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close){

        /** Called when drawer is closed */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        /** Called when a drawer is opened */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle("Выбирите тему");
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    // Setting DrawerToggle on DrawerLayout
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    // Creating an ArrayAdapter to add items to the listview mDrawerList
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.drawer_list_item ,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rivers)
    );

    // Setting the adapter on mDrawerList
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Enabling Home button
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // Enabling Up navigation
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Setting item click listener for the listview mDrawerList
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View view,
                                int position,
                                long id) {

            // Getting an array of rivers
            String[] rivers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rivers);

            //Currently selected river
            mTitle = rivers[position];

            // Creating a fragment object
            Fragment rFragment=null;

            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    rFragment = new RiverFragment();
                break;
                case 1:
                    rFragment = new RiverFragment1();
                break;
            }

            // Creating a Bundle object
            Bundle data = new Bundle();

            // Setting the index of the currently selected item of mDrawerList
            data.putInt("position", position);

            // Setting the position to the fragment
            rFragment.setArguments(data);

            // Getting reference to the FragmentManager
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            // Creating a fragment transaction
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            // Adding a fragment to the fragment transaction
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, rFragment);

            // Committing the transaction
            ft.commit();

            // Closing the drawer
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    });
    setupSearchView();
}

public void setupSearchView() {
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

/** Handling the touch event of app icon */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/** Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);

    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    mSearchView= (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
        mListView.clearTextFilter();
    } else {
        mListView.setFilterText(s.toString());
    }
    return true;
}
```

}</i>
Сама ошибка:

> Process: com.xpdev.discretmath, PID:
> 12087
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.xpdev.discretmath/com.xpdev.discretmath.BaseActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
> Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
> Method)
>      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>             at com.xpdev.discretmath.BaseActivity.setupSearchView(BaseActivity.java:151)
>             at com.xpdev.discretmath.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:147)
>             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
> Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
> Method)

Comment: @Kl0nLutiy, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setupSearchView() вызывается в конце onCreate(), но mSearchView иннициализируется в onCreateOptionsMenu(). Почему бы просто не вызвать setupSearchView() сразу после иннициализации mSearchView в onCreateOptionsMenu()? По всей видимости onCreateOptionsMenu() вызывается после или во время исполнения onCreate.